# AngularJS xml data to json data for charts (Edited)

Tags: javascript, json, xml, angularjs

I'm having trouble converting some xml data to json data in the format it is expected. I'm new to all of these techniques and the resources I find online are difficult for me to decypher. Using the app I make in my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Mn4xSOy3xBja2shXZlf?p=preview), I can take the data in the `data.json` file and use it to create the chart using a charts library. I have the xml in the `data.xml` file - I think that it is in the correct format in order to be converted to json in the required format. How do I use the x2js library in order to convert the xml to json and implement it into my chart? I've been stuck on this for a while now, and haven't been able to figure out how to get it working.

Currently, the app takes the `data.json` file and implements it into the data for the charts. What is the easiest way to take the xml and do the same?

Edit: I've updated my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Mn4xSOy3xBja2shXZlf?p=preview) with my attempt at converting the xml data to json. I even tried simply printing out the final data in json form - if the xml converted to json, but nothing came up. I entered a `x2js.js` file that has the functions from the library needed for the conversion I used in the service. I get the following error:

```
     ReferenceError: data is not defined
at new <anonymous> (script.js:38)
at invoke (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3641)
at Object.instantiate (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3653)
at code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:6684
at code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:6097
at forEach (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:307)
at nodeLinkFn (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:6084)
at compositeLinkFn (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:5550)
at compositeLinkFn (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:5553)
at publicLinkFn (code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:5458)
```

If anyone can help me out, its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, You have a couple of problems here:

**The XML:**

I took a small subset of your data and tried to see what the problem was:

```
<Header Name="TOP 5 AUDITORS BY INDUSTRY"><series>Industry_count</series><series>AuditFees</series><data><x>ERNST & YOUNG LLP</x><y>298</y><y>12567000</y></data></Header>
```

x2js doesnt seem to like the `&` in your xml. Basically with the string `ERNST & YOUNG` you're breaking whatever it is x2js is trying to do internally.

```
x2js.xml_str2json('<Header Name="TOP 5 AUDITORS BY INDUSTRY"><series>Industry_count</series><series>AuditFees</series><data><x>ERNST & YOUNG LLP</x><y>298</y><y>12567000</y></data></Header>')
```

doesn't work whereas

```
x2js.xml_str2json('<Header Name="TOP 5 AUDITORS BY INDUSTRY"><series>Industry_count</series><series>AuditFees</series><data><x>ERNST YOUNG LLP</x><y>298</y><y>12567000</y></data></Header>')
```

works and gives a JS object as output. The only thing missing from the second one is the &.

**The Code:**

I also removed the `getData` function and stopped passing the `data` variable into the service (You dont yet have data, which is why youre calling the service). Also added a success handler to set the scope variable.

**Fully fixed working plnkr is here:** http://plnkr.co/edit/uCLy42wnELYKq8S1DjYs?p=preview

Comment: I did not consider special characters in the xml, thank you for your help!

Comment: @NickBorisenko No problem, Happy to help :)